# Android Kotlin Flow data is not collecting from StateFlow and SharedFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

During investigation Kotlin Flow in Android I am trying to understand and (maybe) replace LiveData to Flow. But I don't understand how to collect and emit data under the hood in StateFlow and SharedFlow. Below is quick example and what I mean:

Example data class

```
data class SimpleDto(val value: Int)
```

Example ViewModel

```
class SimpleViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiDtoState = MutableStateFlow(SimpleDto(1))
    val uiDtoState: StateFlow<SimpleDto> = _uiDtoState.asStateFlow()

    fun testCollectData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val tempList = listOf(
                SimpleDto(1),
                SimpleDto(2),
                SimpleDto(3),
                SimpleDto(4),
                SimpleDto(5)
            )
            for (dto in tempList) {
                _uiDtoState.value = dto
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And collect data in Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val viewModel: SimpleViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //...
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                launch {
                    viewModel.uiDtoState.drop(1).collect { result ->
                        Log.d("MyTag", "uiDtoState collected = ${result?.value}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

So, when I call viewModel. testCollectData() it collects just last object SimpleDto(5).

**Question 1:** I assume StateFlow stores only one data (state). It's better to use when it needs just like a flag data (for example Boolean).

This problem can be fix if use SharedFlow, but which config? For example:

```
    val uiDtoState: MutableSharedFlow<SimpleDto> = MutableSharedFlow(
        replay = 1,
        onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST,
    )
```

it collects also only last object. It's clear because *replay=1*.

**Question 2:** What config of SharedFlow should we use if I don't know how to count of data will be store?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one difference between StateFlow and LiveData is that StateFlow doesn’t guarantee all of the intermediate values will be collected. The assumption with “state” is that you only care about the current value and don’t care about any history. In this case, since you are not relinquishing the main thread between calls to set new values to the StateFlow, collectors on the main dispatcher will never even have the opportunity to see intermediate values.

LiveData, on the other hand immediately fires its observers synchronously when you update its value on the main thread.

If you don’t know how much history you need for a SharedFlow, you should set `replay` to `Int.MAX_VALUE`. But the downside is that it will keep a history going back forever. New collectors will end up collecting the entire history of values even if some are obsolete, so this isn’t the same behavior you would have had with LiveData, which doesn’t replay values for new observers.

One possible hack to allow current collectors of the StateFlow on the main dispatcher to get all the values would be to call `yield()` inside your loop that is setting values. I’m not sure if this is a robust solution though. It’s relying on the assumption that the Main Dispatcher is submitting pieces of coroutines to the main Looper to be executed, so calling `yield()` would always put the next iteration of the loop after collectors have all had a chance to collect the previous value. It’s also assuming your collect function doesn’t make any suspend function calls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not sure that Int.MAX_VALUE for replay for SharedFlow is a good idea, because data always collects and stores inside and I assume it will increase memory. Also I need always fresh data, but SharedFlow collects data and doesn't clear old. And one more problem is when activity/fragment stop and start again all data (old and latest) from SharedFlow will collect. This behavior is not suitable.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like neither StateFlow or SharedFlow is suitable for your requirements to (a) not miss intermediate values (b) not store or replay old values. You might consider looking into Channels, but LiveData is probably most suited to your task.